# How to: validate if a sequence of points form a polygon

Tags: geometry

I stumble on following question during programming task: given a sequence or list of non-coincidental points, I want to know if they compose a polygon.

My thoughts sofar are: They cannot be a polygon if they:

1. Sidelines are coincidental;
2. A sideline intersects any of the other $n-1$ sidelines.

But how?

Given lines $r$ and $s$ given by equalities $A + \lambda (P_{01} - P_{00})$ and $B + \mu (P_{11} - P_{10})$, the lines intersect only if equality $P_{00} + \lambda \underbrace{(P_{01} - P_{00})}_{u} = P_{01} + \mu \underbrace{(P_{11} - P_{10})}_{v}$ holds. It means, there is tuple $(\lambda, \mu) \in \mathbb{R}^2_+$ such that $\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix} u & -v \end{bmatrix}}_W \begin{bmatrix} \lambda \\ \mu \end{bmatrix} = P_{01} - P_{00} $. Since both points $P_{00}$ and $P_{10}$ are sequantially given, both parameters $\lambda$ and $\mu$ must be positive.

There is the condition still where matrix determinant $W$ is 0, which means the sidelines are parallel. Therefore, truth-function in this case is $[(\lambda, \mu) \in \mathbb{R}^2_+] \wedge [det(W) \neq 0]$

Can you see any flaw on my rationale? Thanks!

Comment: What is your definition of "polygon", and of "sequence of points form a polygon"? For instance, does the list  $[(0,1), (1,0), (0,1), (1,0),(1,0)]$ form a polygon according to your definition?

Comment: From [Wikipedia:](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon) "A polygonal chain may cross over itself, creating star polygons and other self-intersecting polygons." I'm guessing you want *simple polygons*, but do you allow concave polygons, or only convex?

Comment: @kimchilover I will change the post to consider non-duplicate points. Thanks!

Comment: @DanielMathias Both concave and convex polygons are adequate. Therefore, simple pollygons.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, but are missing one thing that is important to correctly identify concave polygons. For 2 line segments to intersect (possibly at the end points), not only must $\lambda, \mu$ be non-negative, but they must also be less than or equal to $1$.

[image: concave quadrilateral]

If you ignore the latter condition, your algorithm will think that in the above picture the line segments $P_{00}P_{P01}$ and $P_{10}P_{P11}$ intersect. If you add the condition, you see the the line segments do not intersect because the $\mu$ value is bigger than $1$.

If $\det(W)=0$, you have to decide if the segments are on the same line or not. If not, they don't intersect. If they are, you need to determine if they intersect. You can do this for example by expressing $P_{10}$ and $P_{P11}$ in the form $P_{10} = P_{00} + \xi_0(P_{01}-P_{00})$ and $P_{11} = P_{00} + \xi_1(P_{01}-P_{00})$, and determine $\xi_0$ and $\xi_1$, resp. The segments on the same line do **not** intersect, iff both $\xi_0$ and $\xi_1$ are smaller than $0$ or both are bigger than $1$. Otherwise, they intersect.